# How to Relate Two Fields in One Table to One Field in Another

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm an Access rookie, so this is probably an easy answer. I have a table of retail products that has three columns called Group1, Group2, and Group3. Each group column has a number in it from 0-90 that represents the type of product that it is. I have a separate table of group #s and their descriptions. (So a can of coke would get Group1 = 9 for beverage, Group2 = 21 for soda, and Group3 = 71 for can.)

If I create a query to list each item description and the three group codes, but I want the group name to appear, how do I create that relationship between the two tables, since Group1, 2, and 3 all relate back to Group#?

Here are the two tables:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the relationship diagram, you can add the same GroupCodes table multiple times by right-clicking in an empty area and choosing Add Table. You'll want to create 3 relationships with the same table, but once for each box, from "Group#" to each Item field MA Group 1,2 and 3.

In the Join Properties for each relationship (right-click on the relationship line), you'll want to use option "Include ALL records from Item List and only those from GroupCodes where the joined fields are equal", since I suppose some items have not all groups filled. In SQL, that's called a left outer join.